# Installing Ubuntu onn SSD (2nd) and documents on hdd (main) on Dell Studio 1737

Tags: partitioning

I am new to Linux in regards attempting installation etc. In past months my several PC's have repeatedly crashed rendering not only my OS unusable but apparently the document folders as well. This includes a Dell 1737, an HP Dv6, HP Envy and a home built PC and various versions of Linux (12.04, 14.04. Linux Mint) and Win 7 & Win 10.

The laptops/PC run for a month or two, then I get various error messages on booting saying there is no system, or just the Blue screen with cursor prompting.

I would like to install Ubuntu on the SSD which is in the 2nd port, and the documents folders on the main drive which is a 750Gb HDD. Although I have not discovered why my several PC's are repeatedly having boot issues it is my hope that until I can discover the problem, at least I can preserve my documents.

Recently I installed ubuntu on the SSd but when attempting to re-boot, the system did not recognize the OS. All of the posts about this bring up "dual boot"(ing) where as prefer to install Windows on a separate laptop
I am perplexed and would appreciate any help/instruction as to how to accomplish this installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) – Your question is quite vague so I'm not sure what else to tell you. If you encounter an issue during the installation please report back.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the system recognize your Ubuntu, you have to change the boot order in bios. After turning on your computer press either F2 or F12 (sometimes it Delete key)  and go to bios munu, in the "Boot" tab change boot order. It also could be in the advanced tab.

[image: like this one]

If you want to have your documents on your HDD. You just have to set your HOME PARTITION (/home) on that drive while installing Ubuntu.

[image]

In the picture you see a box named Mount Point. Its on Root Partition (/) by default. You can set root on SDD and after that select your HDD and click on + sign and from this box select /home.
That will do it.